# Centered node names

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I want to draw a graph with square nodes containing roman numerals. It has to be big enough that the number VIII fits in, and I would like to have all squares the same size. I got it so far, unfortunately my roman numerals are not centered. Can someone tell me how to center them?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\newcommand{\rom}[1]{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral #1\relax}}
%\tikzset{square/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4,inner sep=0}}
\begin{document}    
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    square/.style={
    draw,
    regular polygon, regular polygon sides=4,
    text width={width("\rom{1}")},
    %text width={width("\rom{8}")},
    align=center,
    font=\small}]
\node[square] (iv) at (0,2) {\rom{4}};
\node[square] (v) at (0,1) {\rom{5}};
\node[square] (vi) at (0,0) {\rom{6}};
% \node[shape=rectangle,draw=black] (viii) at (3,0) {\rom{8}};

\node[shape=circle,draw=black] (0) at (2,2) {0};

\node at (0,0) [square,draw] (viii) {\rom{8}};
\node at (1,0) [square,draw] (i) {\rom{1}};
\node at (2,0) [square,draw] (ii) {\rom{2}};
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add to every node option `text width=width("\rom{8}"), text centered`. You could also create a style.

Comment: If I write     \node at (0,0) [square,draw, text centered] (v100) {\rom{8}}; it is still not centered, nor is it when i include it in the style of the square. And i would like to keep the size as small as it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had two nodes at `(0,0)`. Was that on purpose? If you position the nodes at fixed coordinates, they may overlap. Here is a proposal using relative positioning and CarLaTeX's suggestions.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\newcommand{\rom}[1]{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral #1\relax}}
%\tikzset{square/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4,inner sep=0}}
\begin{document}    
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    square/.style={
    draw,
    regular polygon, regular polygon sides=4,
    %text width={width("\rom{1}")},
    text width={width("\rom{8}")},
    text centered,
    align=center,inner sep=-3pt, %<- you can play with this value
    font=\small}]
\node[square] (iv) at (0,2) {\rom{4}};
\node[square,below=0.2cm of iv] (v)  {\rom{5}};
\node[square,below=0.2cm of v] (vi) {\rom{6}};
% \node[shape=rectangle,draw=black] (viii) at (3,0) {\rom{8}};

\node[shape=circle,draw=black] (0) at (2,2) {0};

\node[square,draw,right=0.2cm of vi]  (viii) {\rom{8}};
\node[square,draw,right=0.2cm of viii] (i) {\rom{1}};
\node[square,draw,right=0.2cm of i] (ii) {\rom{2}};
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry the two nodes at (0,0) were not on purpose.

Comment: @mabu No worries, I was assuming this anyway. That was a very nice first question!